# Get count of a row if value exists

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the count if value exists on datatable

```
String searchAuthor = "John Grisham"     
bool contains = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                .Any(row => searchAuthor == row.Field<String>("Author"));
```

It will help me to check whether specific data is there or not
but want to get count of Author column if data exists

Edited:

I want to get the count of "Author" Column if data exists
Dont want to get the count of rows contains "John Grisham" in "Author"

Comment: Instead of matching against some value, why aren't you matching against an empty string or null if you want the number of rows that contain a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
String searchAuthor = "John Grisham"     
var count = tbl.AsEnumerable().Count(row => searchAuthor == row.Field<String>("Author"));
```

EDIT: To get data count having not null or empty authors

```
var count = tbl.AsEnumerable().Count(row => row.Field<String>("Author") != null && row.Field<String>("Author").Trim() != string.Empty);
```

OR

```
var count = tbl.AsEnumerable().Count(row => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<String>("Author")));
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of rows where `Author` is non-empty, try:

```
var count = tbl.AsEnumerable()
               .Count(row => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Field<String>("Author"));
```

This results in a single check and avoids generating temporary strings like `Trim` does. This can be important if you have many rows or you need to perform filtering frequently.